Angular Firebase: Login Page Flicker on Refresh (AuthGuard + redirectUnauthorizedTo)
I'm encountering an issue where the login page briefly flashes on refresh before redirecting me to the intended URL when using Firebase Authentication with Angular.
Ideally, the login page should only appear if the user isn't authenticated. On refresh within authenticated routes, the user should remain on the current page.
Here's the relevant code from my app.routes.ts and app.config.ts files:
// app.routes.ts
import { AuthGuard, redirectLoggedInTo, redirectUnauthorizedTo } from '@angular/fire/auth-guard';

const redirectUnauthorizedToLogin = () => redirectUnauthorizedTo(['/login']);
const redirectLoggedInToHome = () => redirectLoggedInTo(['']);

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data: { authGuardPipe: redirectUnauthorizedToLogin },
  },
  // ... other routes
];

// app.config.ts
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/fire/compat';
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideHttpClient(withInterceptors([bearerTokenInterceptor])),
    importProvidersFrom([
      provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig)),
      provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
    ]),
  ],
};

Versions:

Angular: 17.3.4
Node: 21.7.1
@angular/fire: 17.0.1



The issue is due to enabling SSR, since there is no window or localStorage on the server, the login page is getting generated on the server and when sent to frontend, just before the UI is run again (hydration I guess!), we see a flash of the login page.
To solve this issue, all you need to do is make the login page show nothing when it's generated on the server, then it gives the impression that the app is loading. Alternatively you could also show the splash screen with a loader on the login page, when the mode is server, this will get rid of this bug.
TS:
...
export class LoginComponent {
  isUser = signal(false)
  isServer = false;
  
  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private router: Router, private tokenService: TokenService, 
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) platformId: Object){
      this.isServer = isPlatformServer(platformId);
    console.log('aqui')
    const userToken = this.tokenService.getToken()
    if(userToken){
      this.isUser.set(true)
    }
  }
  ...

HTML:
@if (!this.isUser() && !isServer) {
    <p>login works!</p>
<button mat-raised-button (click)="login()"> LOGIN </button>
}

Github Repo

Spinner example
HTML
@if(isServer) {
    <div style="height:100vh;width:100vw;background-color: rgb(194, 24, 91); display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
        <div id="loading"></div>
    </div>
} @else {
    @if (!this.isUser()) {
        <p>login works!</p>
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="login()"> LOGIN </button>
    }
}

CSS
#loading {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top-color: #fff;
  animation: spin 1s ease-in-out infinite;
  -webkit-animation: spin 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

TS:
export class LoginComponent {
  isServer = false;
  isUser = signal(false)

  constructor(
    private auth: AuthService, 
    private router: Router, 
    private tokenService: TokenService,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) platformId: Object){
      this.isServer = isPlatformServer(platformId);
    console.log('aqui')
    const userToken = this.tokenService.getToken()
    if(userToken){
      this.isUser.set(true)
    }
  }

Github Repo

I had the same issue, and was able to use a similar implementation to this. I appreciate it!
